# how can i set cookie for toggle div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a little problem with div toggle. In my page I have two main divs, one is box and the other one is box2.

When the user opens my page at first only box is visible, but when he/she clicks on box2 it slides down and shows.

After the user toggles box2, on page reload that div has to be open but I don't know how to set the cookie for that.

Please check here(http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/18/)

```
function getCookie(c_name) {
var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
    x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
    x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    if (x == c_name) {
        return unescape(y);
      }
   }
}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
var exdate = new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays === null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

var widget2 = $(".widget2"),
box2 = $(".box2");

widget2.hide();
box2.click(function() {
$(this).next(widget2).slideToggle("fast", function() {});
});

var inner = $(".inner"),
box = $(".box");

inner.hide();
box.click(function() {
$(this).next(inner).slideToggle("fast", function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: If user opens all divs, after reload they all need to be opened?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to store the status of the box and then use getcookie to check the status on page reload and then toggle it accordingly

```
box2.click(function() {
    $(this).next(widget2).slideToggle("fast", function() {
        var flag = ($(this).css("display") == 'none')?'off':'on';
        setCookie('box2', flag);
    });
});
```

And then on page reload check for the status/value of the box and then toggle accordingly.
something like

```
if(getCookie('box2') == 'on'){
    box2.show();
}else{
    box2.hide();
}
```

Not the exact solution but jus giving you some way you will be able to handle it

if you have a doubt regarding whether your setcookie and getcookie are correct, you can refer this [link on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) for simple implementation of the cookies

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay. but this code is not working. when i reload my page this div are reset. Please check here http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/20/

Comment: ofcourse they will be reset because you have to do it manually (i mean by putting checks) to put it back to the status depending on the cookie set previously... let me try at jsfiddle

Comment: ya i also think that same but whenever I trying to set checks so that toggle div are stopped and all div are open.

Comment: I got some solution in. when I check cookie's value so it's give me the value but not give the current value means in above **get cookie** condition it will show or hide all box2 but I need it's current value which I can't get right now. so is there any idea to get current value of it please check here.[example](http://jsfiddle.net/wasimkazi/fauNg/23/)